# Silverstripe 3.1 Is the title/name of a field available in an ss template?

Tags: silverstripe

For example

```
static $db = array('CarName' => 'Text')
public static $summary_fields = array('CarName' => 'Car Name')
```

In the ss template this will show the value of the field called CarName

```
<p>$CarName</p>
```

Can I also display the title that I included in my $summary_field ie. 'Car Name' instead of just typing it in manually in the ss template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote this function which works, put it in the Page_Controller of the page your using -

```
public function getSummaryFlds() {
    $getSummFlds = $this->owner->summaryFields();
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($getSummFlds as $dbfield => $title) {
        $value = $this->$dbfield;
        $newArr[] = ArrayData::create(array('Title' => $title, 'Value' => $value));
    }
    var_dump($getSummFlds);
    $newArray = ArrayList::create(
                $newArr
            );
    $result = $newArray;
    return $result;
}
```

Then in the ss template

```
<% loop $SummaryFlds %>
    <dt>$Title</dt><dd>$Value</dd>
<% end_loop %>
```

Result is all the $summary_fields with the title and value.

Comment: Using `owner` in a Controller context is wrong. You only need `owner` in an Extension.. when using in a controller, you can skip the owner and just write `$this->summaryFields();`. You should also remove the `var_dump`....

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no direct accessor to individual summary fields. You could write a simple extension that does that for you though. Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
class SummaryExtension extends DataExtension
{
    public function SummaryField($fieldName){
        $fields = $this->owner->summaryFields();
        if(isset($fields[$fieldName])){
            return $fields[$fieldName];
        }
        return $fieldName;
    }
}
```

Then add the extension to your DataObject either via `_config.yml` or directly as static variable:

```
private static $extensions = array('SummaryExtension');
```

In the template, you can then output the title by writing:

```
$SummaryField('CarName')
```

Comment: Thanks the line $this->owner->summaryFields(); was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work but there's a [getName() function on DBField](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DBField.html) so I would try $CarName.Name

Comment: That only gives the DBField Name not the title from $summary_fields, sorry